# Redirect store view

Tags: multistore, url-rewrite, store-view

I have two store view

IT 
EN

My defualt store views is IT

but if I connect to **www.mydomain.com** not redirect to **www.mydomain.com/it/**

Comment: If the default is IT then it wouldn't need a redirect? How have you tried to put the redirect in place?

Comment: I wanted to try with .htaccess but do not understand anything